# How to connect my whatsapp chatbot to my own number?

Tags: twilio, chatbot, whatsapp

I've been using Twilio for developing a whatsapp chatbot.
I've deployed it to a URL and now I want to connect this server to my own Whatsapp business.
how can I do it?
And also if I have X clients who wants me to build a WA chatbot for them, how can I connect this bot to their whatsapp business account?